# Bootstrap tab navigation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I did a very simple setup for bootstrap tabs navigation according to http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs and http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="test_tab">
    <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
        <span>Hello 1!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <span>Hello 2!</span>
    </div>
</div>

$(function () {
    $('#test_tab a').click(function (e) {
        console.info("clicked!");
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
});
```

However, it's not working correctly. When I click on a tab (e.g. tab2), it gets activated as desired, however I can't click it again. When I click on tab 1, tab 1 get's activated, but tab 2 stays activated aswell.

For clarification:

**Start**

```
Tab 1 | Tab 2
-----------------
```

**Click on Tab 2**

```
Tab 1 | Tab 2
-----------------
Hello 2!
```

**Click on Tab 1**

```
Tab 1 | Tab 2
-----------------
Hello 2!
Hello 1!
```

Comment: @Pavlo I did, yes. But no effect, except that the first element is active at startup. :(

Comment: Actually I don't see any problems with your code, check this one http://jsfiddle.net/gfb3d/

Comment: @Pavlo Yes, I don't see anything off either. Might be something wrong with my bootstrap CSS, but I did nothing else than copying the bootstrap.css from the current release. :/

Comment: You have missed to include bootstrap.js then :) Try to use Firebug and see Errors console before posting a question

Comment: @Pavlo Bootstrap.js is included and can be found. On my main page: @Scripts.Render("~/js/bootstrap") -> routes to "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js" which renders as '/js/bootstrap?v=vQ_Gu0D_BsZTQ6TY6akag53T-LlmZIdGmqSBMX-BKt41' (page source code) which has the minified bootstrap.js behind.

Comment: As I said, you should check the Error console to find out what is wrong, I reckon this is connected to incorrect included file, because as you can see your code works perfect in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap's data-* syntax, you don't have to write any JS unless you want to manually show a tab (say you want to show a tab when a button is clicked or a function is ran, rather than clicking on it in the nav).

I couldn't reproduce your issue in jsFiddle, but what I suspect is going on is the click binding is manually showing tab 1, and preventing bootstrap from hiding the others.

Try removing the click handler, and relying only on bootstrap's `data-toggle="tab"`

Comment: also should that not work, I just noticed you're missing a semicolon after `e.preventDefault()`. Depending on the browser you're using, this could break the page; check the log to see if you're getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Met exactly the same problem, actually need to add the 'active' class to the tab-pane as well.

```js
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <span>Hello 1!</span>
</div>
```

Found the reference here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#fade-effect